# remina pulldown menu not present

Tags: release-loki, apps, rdp

after using remina (RDP app) for a while in full screen mode ... the pulldown menu stops working in Loki .... I dont know if this is a remina or Loki bug or maybe something else entirely ... any ideas of what could be causing this or how to get the pulldown menu to continue to be responsive? additional information ... if I end the session and restart it ... it seems like the pulldown is again active ... for a while ... then again become unresponsive

Answer (score 1):

I use Remina ever day for work, and I have experienced this bug on occasion. What helps for me at least is to delete the connection, and then re-do it, and the bug should stay gone. I've only had it happen once or twice in the last few months.

And to make you feel better, I think it's a Remina bug, because this used to happen to me back when I used Xubuntu as well.

Not optimal, but at least it's a usable workaround.
Hope that helps.

Comment: oh well ... re-creating the session doesn't work ... I even "pinned" the menu to see if that would work ... nope ... I guess just going to need to live with it. or find another that I like to use ... It is a shame that the "MacOS X cord" app doesnt have a linux version ... that was always enjoyable to use